# Как исправить QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcpsocket

В библиотеке есть функции:

```
int read(void* h, unsigned int b, unsigned int r, unsigned int* v)
{
    QString q = QString("read %1 %2 %3").arg(b).arg(r).arg(*v);
    QString r = query(q);
    qDebug() << "  * (hex)" << hex << r << dec;
    *value = r.toUInt();

    return 0;
}

int write(void* h, unsigned int b, unsigned int r, unsigned int v)
{
    QString q = QString("write %1 %2 %3").arg(b).arg(r).arg(v, 8, 16, QChar('0'));
    QString r = query(q);
    qDebug() << "  * (hex)" << hex << r << dec;

    return 0;
}

QString query(QString _q)
{
    qDebug() << "[query]";

    QString host = "127.0.0.1";
    ushort port = 7777;

    QString reply;

    if (!_connectToHost(host, port))
    {
        reply =  "[ERROR] Connecting to host failed";
    }
    else
    {
        if (QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState == sock.state())
        {
            QByteArray ar = _q.toLatin1();
            sock.write(ar);
            if (sock.waitForBytesWritten())
            {
                qDebug() << "Data were written";
            }
            else
            {
                reply = "[ERROR] Writing data failed";
            }
            if (sock.waitForReadyRead(1000))
            {
                reply = sock.read(1024);
            }
        }
    }
    sock.disconnectFromHost();
    return reply;
}

bool _connectToHost(const QString& _host, const ushort _port)
{
    qDebug() << "[_connectToHost]";

    qDebug() << "  * connecting...";
    sock.connectToHost(_host, _port);

    qDebug() << "  * Waiting for connection...";
    return sock.waitForConnected();
}
```

После вызова query получаю сообщение:

```
* connecting...
Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTcpSocket(0x55555576e3e0), parent's thread is QThread(0x5555557872b0), current thread is QThread(0x7fffffffe450)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTcpSocket(0x55555576e3e0), parent's thread is QThread(0x5555557872b0), current thread is QThread(0x7fffffffe450)
```

Из программы вызываются функции read и write.

Сервер получает строку и даже отвечает, но хотелось бы устранить сообщения. Объясните, пожалуйста, как лечить. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: `Не могу создать дочерние объекты для родителя, который создан в другом потоке` - нужно как-то разобраться в этих родственных связях и не подсовывать чужих детей не в то гнездо. По вашему коду не совсем понятно где тут родитель из другого потока и каких детей ему пытаются подсунуть

Comment: В библиотеке есть еще несколько функций, не связанных с приведенными. В начале файла объявление вида QTcpSocket sock;
bool _connectToHost(const QString& _host, const ushort _port);
QString query(QString _q); query вызывается, чтобы передать данные серверу. Сказать, кто есть родитель не могу.

Comment: Покажите больше кода )

Comment: В библиотеке:
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H

int read(void *, unsigned int, unsigned short );

int write(void *, unsigned int , unsigned short);

QTcpSocket sock;
#endif

Comment: Это код надо из комментариев перенести в вопрос